# Get instance of view in viewmodel Mvvm light/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a window view where I wish to put a Ticker View

```
<Window x:Class="TerminalClient_Mvvmlight.Views.Ticker.TickerView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:TerminalClient_Mvvmlight.Views.Ticker"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        DataContext="{Binding TickerVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" WindowStyle="None" Height="44.949" Width="931.35">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TickerWindowLoaded}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Views:TickerLayout  Grid.Column="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm trying to get the instance of "TickerLayout", because, I need it as a layout for my Ticker, in my viewmodel

```
private void OnTickerWindowLoaded()
{
    MessageBox.Show("TickerView chargé !");
    var v = (TickerLayout)this();
    ticker = new Ticker<TickerNormalView>(new TickerLayout().LayoutRoot);
    ticker.Speed = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    manager.Start();
    ticker.Start();
}
```

I wish to synchrinise "new TickerLayout()" with the instance of TickerLayout in my window when this one is opened after a event. Could you help me to do that ?

Comment: Just an FYI, if you are looking for a view in your view model, you are so not using MVVM. You should think about using a region manager of sorts to inject your views in the appropriate places.

Comment: +1 for 'don't put bits of View in your ViewModel'. You can use MVVM Light's Messenger class to send data between your ViewModel and View without breaking MVVM. Send NotificationMessages (or more complex messages using custom types) from OnTickerWindowLoaded with instructions to make changes to your control. Something like Messenger.Default.Send("StartTicker") . Catch and deal with the message in your View codebehind, triggering any necessary changes to your interface.

Comment: I'm searching in that way since 2 days.. but have you an example ? I'm using an datatemplate, but how I could interact to view control like a canvas ?